# how to retrieve data from strong tags in html file using jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have some html data like

```
<div class="bs-example">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">ABC</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="slimScroller" style="height:280px; position: relative;" data-rail-visible="1" data-always-visible="1">
        <strong>Name:</strong>
        <a href="https://ABC"> </a><br />
        <strong>ID No:</strong> XXXXX<br />
        <strong>Status:</strong> ACTIVE<br />
        <strong>Class:</strong> 5<br />
        <strong>Category:</strong> A<br />
        <strong>Marks:</strong> 500<br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want output as (multiple students data):

```
 Name: ABC
 ID No.: XXXXX
 Status: Active
 Class: 5
 Category: A
 Marks: 500
```

How to get this data using jsoup or any other way? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Element.nextElementSibling() or/and Element.nextSibling() to get the output you need.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Exam {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html =  "<div class=\"bs-example\">" +
                    "  <div class=\"panel panel-primary\">" +
                    "    <div class=\"panel-heading\">" +
                    "      <h3 class=\"panel-title\">ABC</h3>" +
                    "    </div>" +
                    "    <div class=\"panel-body\">" +
                    "      <div class=\"slimScroller\" style=\"height:280px; position: relative;\" data-rail-visible=\"1\" data-always-visible=\"1\">" +
                    "        <strong>Name:</strong>" +
                    "        <a href=\"https://ABC\"> </a><br />" +
                    "        <strong>ID No:</strong> XXXXX<br />" +
                    "        <strong>Status:</strong> ACTIVE<br />" +
                    "        <strong>Class:</strong> 5<br />" +
                    "        <strong>Category:</strong> A<br />" +
                    "        <strong>Marks:</strong> 500<br />" +
                    "      </div>" +
                    "    </div>" +
                    "  </div>" +
                    "</div>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements eles = doc.select("div.slimScroller strong");
    for(Element e :eles)
    System.out.println(e.text() +
                       ( e.nextElementSibling().tagName().equals("a")? 
                         e.nextElementSibling().attr("href").replace("https://", ""):
                         e.nextSibling().toString()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eritrean, really appreciate the help...but this throws a null pointer exception at         ( e.nextElementSibling().tagName().equals("a")?

Comment: Have you tried this with your original html snippet or the snippet edited by @anurag? There might be something missing in your first posted snippet. With the html included in the code i don't get a NPE.

Comment: I tried this on the original snippet. My "a" tag reads as:   <strong>Name:</strong> <a href="https://example.com/student/details/ABC">ABC</a><br />

Answer (score 0):

The following code should provide the output specified based off your comment describing how your `a` tags are:

```
private static void printStudentInfo(Document document){
    Elements students = document.select("div.slimScroller strong");

    for(Element student : students){
        System.out.print(student.text());

        System.out.println(student.nextElementSibling().tagName().equals("a") ?
                student.nextElementSibling().text() : student.nextSibling().toString());
    }
}
```